# I need with arithmetic SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Table where i have 4 Column
Table Name: Topup

```
------------------------------------
Status | Adjustment | Kisok | Done  |
 Yes   |   232      |  Abc  |  ok   |  
 NO    |  Null      |  Adc  |  No   |
-------------------------------------
```

I want the Status = YES 
when  Adjustment , Kisok and Done Is not Null 
and if Status = No
then Adjustment , Kisok and Done can have both null and Not null

I Want This Query in arithmetic SQL Query like (and, or)
and if not 
Case and If else is fine
If you can help me that would me fine

I known that the Logic is fine but the i am not clear about the syntax

This Query is wrong>>

```
SELECT Status1,csdoneby,kioskdoneby,adjtmentstype,
   (CASE
    WHEN csdoneby,kioskdoneby,adjtmentstype, IS NOT NULL THEN Status1='yes'
    ELSE Status='No'
END as Test)
FROM topup;
```

Comment: Can this query be written by Arithmetic Operator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Like This

```
SELECT Status1, csdoneby, kioskdoneby, adjtmentstype,
       CASE WHEN csdoneby IS NOT NULL AND kioskdoneby IS NOT NULL AND adjtmentstype IS NOT 
       NULL THEN 'yes'
       ELSE 'No'
       END AS Test
FROM topup;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should assign  the condition to each column

```
SELECT Status1, csdoneby,kioskdoneby, adjtmentstype,
   CASE
    WHEN csdoneby IS NOT NULL 
        AND kioskdoneby IS NOT NULL 
        AND adjtmentstype IS NOT NULL THEN 'yes'
    ELSE 'No'
END as Test
FROM topup;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the right syntax.

```
SELECT 
Status1,
csdoneby,
kioskdoneby,
adjtmentstype,
CASE
    WHEN csdoneby IS NOT NULL
         AND kioskdoneby  IS NOT NULL
         AND adjtmentstype  IS NOT NULL
      THEN Status1='yes'
    ELSE 'No'
END as Status
FROM topup
```